# MSSQL + Laravel: "Error by converting varchar to bigint"

Tags: sql-server, laravel, bigint

Actually, I can't insert data into a table with big number.
The primary key has type of BIGINT, when I try to insert a row I'm getting this error.
Same thing happens when I try it manually with HeidiSQL.

Comment: please post which error you got, with details

Comment: Error 8114 converting data type varchar to numeric

Comment: Provide your insert statement,which helps us to provide solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are going to insert string/varchar/nvarchar data to your BIGINT type column. please check your data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. It's been caused by a trigger in the database, which tried to put a string with "8001049473-A1-R" into a bigint field. After deleting that row containing the "8001049473-A1-R", everything works.